# nodejs ENOENT after update

Tags: node.js

I've updated nodejs from v.0.10.26 to v.0.10.28 and suddently this piece of code:

```
// Start slave process
var process = require('child_process');
var ls = process.exec('node slave.js', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error.stack);
        console.log('Error code: '+error.code);
        console.log('Signal received: '+error.signal);
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    }
    else{
        console.log('ok!');
    }

});
```

started to dump this error to the console:

```
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:998:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:34)
Error code: ENOENT
Signal received: undefined
stdout:
stderr:
```

I'm running Windows 8.1 x64. I've tryied to find a solution this entire morning and can't find what is causing this.

**EDIT 1**

slave.js is in the same directory as the main file.

**EDIT 2**

Just to be sure that node could find 'slave.js', I used this code:

```
fs.exists('slave.js', function(exists) {
    if (exists) {
        console.log('It exists!');
    }
});
```

And yes, Node says that the file exists.

**EDIT 3**
Reverted to node 0.10.26. Same issue. I've downgraded from Python 3 to 2.7. Can this be related?

Comment: Is slave.js in the same directory as the script containing the code you've posted? Same directory that you're executing the posted code from? What if you try `'node ' + __dirname + '\\slave.js'` instead?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that on the question. (edited to add this info)

Comment: BTW, just now I tried to use the global path to the file (like you said) but returned the same error.

Comment: I've also reinstalled Python. Could this be related?

Comment: why you don't use `child_process.fork()` for node scripts?

Comment: another thought, you should not overwrite `process`, try to name it `cp`, this may cause also a problem

Comment: This looks like a node.js bug. I wonder anyone can reproduce this on windows.

Comment: micninc, I've used exec because there are some chances that the "slave" node script that runs in background will be rewritten in some other language. (and renamed process to cp. same result.)

Comment: Farid Nouri Neshat, I've tryied to run with jxcore (the most recent. I dont' know what's the version of nodeJs brach) and it returned the same error. I will reboot my computer to see if it's something else.

Comment: No, reboot does not help.

Comment: Reverted to node 0.10.26. Same issue. I've downgraded from Python 3 to 2.7. Can this be related?

Comment: Can execute another command other than `node`?  Maybe it's `node` that can't be found, not the `slave.js` file.

Comment: @dylants, It seems that this was the problem. Uninstalling and installing node and python could have messed up my path (later yesterday I found that I couldn't "ping" anything). So, I added c:\windows\system32 to my path and everything works fine now. Could you please post it as a answer so I can accept it? Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's not the `slave.js` file which can not be found, but `node` itself.  Try checking your path to see if `node` remains in the path following the upgrade.